# increasing app badge number on iphone app

Tags: java, iphone, push-notification

i use Java pns for the push on my app,
this is how i use it:

```
    public static PushedNotifications Push(String token,String message,String Sound,int badge) throws CommunicationException, KeystoreException{    
         String key=PushUtil.class.getResource("cert.p12").getPath();
         PushedNotifications pn= Push.combined(message, badge, Sound, key, "Pass", true, token);
         System.out.println("pn: "+pn);
         return pn;         
    }
```

is there a way to send a notification with the amount to increase the badge instead of
just setting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. The badge number is *just* a replacement. If it's meant to reflect some sort of state, you should maintain that state in your server, and always push the absolute value.